# Django SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE doesn't work

Tags: python, django, session

I would like to log out user if browser is closed. I added `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True` to my settings.py and the following function to my `base.html` file but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
  $(window).on("beforeunload", function(e) {
      $.ajax({
              url: logout_view,
              method: 'GET',
          })
  });
});
```

What am I missing and how to solve it? I am using Django 3.2.